# I'm trying to train the model using keras library but I'm getting value error

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, lstm

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Embedding(input_dim=2954, output_dim=64))
model.add(layers.LSTM(128))
model.add(layers.Dense(10))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

> ValueError: A target array with shape (1, 2954) was passed for output
>   of shape (None, 10) while using as loss categorical_crossentropy. This
>   loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.

Answer (score 0):

Check your targets/labels. Your targets should be one-hot-encoded, since you are using `categorical_crossentropy` as loss function. The error complains that instead of having a shape of `(batch_size, 10)`, your targets array has a shape of `(1, 2954)`

**P.S.** your last `Dense` layer should have a softmax activation function:

```
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```